# Verificar una cadena de conexión SQL, con autentificación SQL Server en visual studio 2022

Tags: c#

Quiero realizar una validación de cadena de conexión para realizar un formulario de inicio de sesión, donde el formulario estará el usuario y contraseña, después guardar esa cadena de conexión para así realizar las altas y bajas en el entorno gráfico.

Mediante clases realice una verificación, pero al darle el botón de iniciar sesión teniendo datos en los textbox o no abre mi formulario principal.

Las clases que use son las siguientes:

```
    internal class Conexion
    {
        public static SqlConnection Conectar(string user,string contraseña)
        {
            string cadena = "server=EMMANUEL\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Ventas;User ID"+"="+user+";"+ "Password"+"="+contraseña;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadena);
            return conexion;
        }

    }
}



   internal class Modelo
    {
        public bool Verificar_Conexion(string user, string contraseña)
        {
            bool resultado;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conexion = Conexion.Conectar(user, contraseña))
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    return resultado = true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return resultado=false;
            }
        }
        
    }
}



internal class Control
    {
        public string ctrluser(string user, string contraseña)
        {
            Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
            string respuesta = "";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(contraseña))
            {
                respuesta = "Llene todos los campos";
            }
            else
            {
                if (modelo.Verificar_Conexion(user, contraseña))
                {
                    respuesta="El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos";
                }
                
            }
            return respuesta;
        }
    }
```

El evento que utilizo para llamar a la clase:

```
   private void buttonIniciarS_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string usuario = textBoxUsuario.Text;
        string contraseña = textBoxContraseña.Text;
        try
        {
            Control control = new Control();
            string respuesta = control.ctrluser(usuario,contraseña);
            if (respuesta.Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(respuesta, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                FormularioPrincipal principal = new FormularioPrincipal();
                principal.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Necesito ayuda, ya que es la primera vez que realizo un inicio de sesión con una autentificación asi y no se que hacer.

Comment: Esto que lenguaje es? si no abre el formulario principal, que es lo que hace? tira un error? que error?

Comment: C#, no me tiene que abrir el formulario si el usuario no existe. No tira error,solo no cumple con la función

Comment: Y que hace? seguiste tu codigo? el codigo es correcto, con lo cual tenes que darnos mas informacion para que te podamos ayudar... segui tu codigo, y fijate donde no hace lo que vos pensas que tiene que hacer...

Comment: fijate que tu problema, no es ni visual studio, ni sql server... es c#...

Comment: Es una parte del código, ya que la parte de la validación la había puesto aquí pero creo no se subió